# Subquery -Not confident

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Im trying to get an output of Supplier’s bank send-To address numbers where the suppliers/vendors are now ex-suppliers but some of these Supplier’s Bank send-Tos are also used by other suppliers that are still valid. So I've to somehow remove the latter from the former. Conditions are that A/B no should be diff from the Supplier’s send-To and Supplier’s send-To should not be 0.

```
SuppbankAB  =       Supplier’s send-To address no 
SuppAB =            Supplier’s address book no 
Suppstatus =        Supplier’s status as a vendor 
ExV =               Ex vendor/supplier
V=                  Valid vendor/supplier
```

Somehow I'm not confident if this is right or not.

```
  select SuppbankAB,SuppAB, Suppstatus 
  from ABTABLE
  where SuppbankAB <> SuppAB 
   and SuppbankAB <> 0 
   and Suppstatus = 'ExV' 
   and SuppbankAB not in
       (select SuppbankAB 
        from ABTABLE
        where SuppbankAB <> SuppAB
          and SuppbankAB <> 0
          and Suppstatus <> 'ExV');
```

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me. Only, you may want to think over if you really want to restrict the subselect to SuppbankAB <> SuppAB. I imagine you might skip addresses here which you would like to exclude from your results as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with aggregation and a `having` clause.  You are looking for `SuppbankAB`s that have both `'ExV'` and non-`'Exv'` values:

```
select SuppbankAB, SuppAB, Suppstatus 
from ABTABLE
where SuppbankAB <> SuppAB and SuppbankAB <> 0 
group by SuppbankAB,SuppAB, Suppstatus 
having sum(case when Suppstatus = 'ExV' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when Suppstatus <> 'ExV' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

The first clause counts the number of rows that have `'ExV'` for each `SuppBankAB`.  It passes when there is at least one.  THe second counts thenumber of rows that don't have that value, and passes when at least one doesn't have the value.